# On click even in jsp

Tags: html, jsp, onclick

I am new in development and in JSP, and I have a school project to make. I have one major issue that is blocking me from continuing to code.

**My issue:** 
I am trying to perform a placement into a variable when the user has clicked a button. 
But in practice, the variable value is the last value in the list. In other words, the `onClick` function is not working.

This is the code:

```
<input type = "submit" id = "buy" name = "buy" value="Buy this <% out.println(rs1.getString("items.item_maker"));%> Now!" onclick = <% car = rs1.getString("items.item_maker").toString(); %> >
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, JSP stands for `Java *Server* Pages`, which means it is executed on the server and not on the client. So you can't invoke a Java method on a click event.

Comment: so i can do some actions in server side when the user clicked the button?

Comment: No, my entire point was that that is impossible...

Comment: You could send an AJAX request, but that will give a hell of a mess.

Comment: i want ot keep it simple :-)

Comment: bro.. Can you re descrine what you trying to do? I dont really make much sense out of your quesrion

Comment: what i want is when user click that html button , its will start an event in server side

Comment: Fumctiom in server side? Jsp is server side. I think you dont understamd what you asking. Do you want to execute some java class function on click?

Comment: Yes i want to execute an methood when the user have clicked the button

Comment: I dint read your code. But [importing java class in jsp](http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/JSP-Servlet/3981-how-to-call-a-java-class-in-jsp.html) should do. And if you want to move to beans, you could improve your code a lot by using beans

Comment: Wait a minute. Buttonclicks are _client-side_, aren't they? Then they should never be possible to trigger a _server-side_ event, isn't it? @MukulGoel

Comment: @11684 : you seem confused with [jsp archietecture](http://onjava.com/onjava/excerpt/jsp2_3/index2.html).button is clicked on client side but interpreted on jsp container(server). Jsp are java server pages.

Comment: I still believe that whatever is within `<% %>` is executed before the client gets the page. Even if not, the `onclick` attribute accepts only javaSCRIPT. @MukulGoel

Comment: @11684 ,sorry, it wasnt you. It was me confused with onclick functionality. You are right about the acriptlets

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible, because JSP is server-side. This means that it is executed before the page arrives at the client. Your code:

```
<input type = "submit" id = "buy" name = "buy" value="Buy this <% out.println(rs1.getString("items.item_maker"));%> Now!" onclick = <% car = rs1.getString("items.item_maker").toString(); %> >
```

Will result in this:

```
<input type = "submit" id = "buy" name = "buy" value="Buy this [string returned by rs1.getString("items.item_maker")] Now!" onclick = [result of rs1.getString("items.item_maker").toString();]>
```

But, since a variable assignment doesn't return anything, this will become

```
<input type = "submit" id = "buy" name = "buy" value="Buy this [string returned by rs1.getString("items.item_maker")] Now!" onclick = >
```

You see, an empty onclick attribute. **EDIT:** I'm actually wrong on that one. An assignment evaluates to the thing being assigned. That's why things like `while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)` work.

Furthermore, the `onclick` attribute accepts only javaSCRIPT which will be executed on click (you don't say). So leaving it empty means `do nothing on click`.

P.S. You miss a closing `</input>` tag, or forgot to add a `/` after the onclick attribute to make it a self-closing tag.